# Can I set ulimit from node.js?

Tags: node.js, ulimit

I'd like to restrict child processes from writing too much data or taking up too much cpu time (infinite loop). In C, I'd call setrlimit(2) to do that. Is there something like this in node.js?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no node.js extension that provides `setrlimit()` functionality, but you can work around the limitation with a small shell workaround hack:

```
/bin/sh -c "ulimit -t 100; exec /usr/bin/node /my/node/program.js"
```

Looks like core node.js will never have `setrlimit()` now that it supports Windows and is no longer a POSIX-only framework: https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/2143

**Update:** I converted the rejected Node patch into a separate `posix` extension module which is now available in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix) and [Github](https://github.com/melor/node-posix).

Comment: I've never thought about the lack of posix support due to the portability. Now that you state it, it seems that it makes much sense. I'll try out your module.

Comment: according to man page ulimit is deprecated so you're stuck with rlimit.

Answer (score 4):

I think this newly-released module is just what you're looking for: https://github.com/melor/node-posix

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any built-in method. However, you can occasionally check the memory usage of a process using [process.memoryUsage()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/process.html#process.memoryUsage) and kill the process manually.

Alternatively, if you know how long it is expected to run, you can specify a timeout as described [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec).