# How to limit number of Websocket connection using websockets/ws lib?

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I want to put a hard limit on the max number of WS connections to max 100. I'm writing a node.js server where I should not allow more than 100 connections.

How to limit the number of Websocket connection **without** touching system **ulimit**?

Comment: how about user ulimit, e.g, `ulimit -n 110`

Comment: @DarrenSmith  I'm running some other server in some other port also. so I cant change ulimit.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on a comment I added, I am able to restrict the amount of websocket connections my server opens by using the **per-session** `ulimit -n` command.

I.e., before starting my websocket server, in a console I run:

`ulimit -n 12`

.. which succeeds (run `ulimit -a` to confirm)

I then start my server and trace its system calls by prefixing the command with *strace*:

`strace -F -f -e trace=network  ./myserver --port 33345`

I then make many concurrent client connections.  After around 6 to 8 are connections are established, further client attempts fail, and I see this in the server strace output:

```
[pid 24344] accept4(10, NULL, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
[pid 24344] accept4(10, NULL, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 9
[pid 24344] accept4(10, NULL, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Note that new terminal sessions don't see this ulimit, I have not changed any server-wide settings.

Comment: I m running some other server in some other port also. so I cant change system ulimit. That I have already specified in my question.

Comment: this is not changing the *system* limit, but the limits associated with a shell.   So can be set for starting individual processes.  More here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75996/modify-ulimit-open-files-of-a-specific-process  and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55319/are-limits-conf-values-applied-on-a-per-process-basis

Comment: Additionally, you can modify your node.js server to sets the ulimit itself, see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141057/can-i-set-ulimit-from-node-js